# Draw view with map in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

What I did here so far is, just created three random views and with the help of the state, I just hide/show the view. However, according to requirements that I have, the logic is the following:
If you click to any close icon (x) it should disappear and in place of this, the view which is standing in the bottom should replace it. Like in Gmail, if you archive message it will be archived and will disappear. The view in the bottom will fill that place.[image]

Can anyone share, small example in order to figure out concept. I understand here that task should be done with array and view should be displayed with a help of map=>. I am bit in confusion since this task requirement concept is brand new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I created for you a small example in which we display cards and when you click on an item, that item is removed.

The code and the working example can be found in the followig [link](https://snack.expo.io/B1l_7aAhH)

```
const App = () => {
  const items = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3']
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState({
    item0: true,
    item1: true,
    item2: true
  });
  const itemClicked = (item) => {
    setVisible({
      ...visible,
      [item]: false
    })
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}> 
      {
        items.map((item, i) => {
          const itemRendered = `item${i}`;

          return (
            <View>
            {
              visible[itemRendered] && 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => itemClicked(itemRendered)} style={styles[itemRendered]}>
              <Text>{item}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            }
            </View>
          ) 
        })  
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

I used the `map` to render 3 clickable items. Those will be displayed only if they should be displayed based on the value of `visible[itemRendered]`. The component keeps the state of which items should be visible or not. In case you click on an item, the state is updated so as the clicked item wont be displayed.